# Join Types in PowerPoint

Tags: .net, vba, powerpoint

VBA or VSTO are okay - OOXML not. Need to use the OM.

I'm looking for a way with the PowerPoint object model to programmatically set the "Join Type" of a given AutoShape to Round, Bevel or Miter. I can't find this in the OM anywhere, but I don't know if it's tucked away somewhere where I'm not looking.

(To see it in PPT2007, choose an AutoShape and get to properties, then "Line Style", then "Join Type).

Anyone know where this bugger may be hidding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like "Join Type" and "Cap Type" are not exposed to the Office object model (this includes Excel as well) - another confirmation: http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/05/interactive-advanced-excel-chart.html

However, a way around it could be to predefine a shape in the PowerPoint document which has these "Join Type" properties set and then use this as a template that you could then use as a source to paste its format onto any other shapes that you have in your documents (or that you create).

Comment: Ah, too bad its not part of the object model. Good idea on getting around this. what I think I'll do is create one shape with like miter and then duplicate and change it's shape 180+ times to get all the shapes. Not fun, but it should work. thanks for your advice.